# UIButtonBackground image smaller then button frame. How do I make equal?

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, uikit

I am skinning `UIButtons` and I've found that my button's width is much wider then what is displayed by the images.

I call the button method below with a specified frame and size:

`CGSize buttonSize = CGSizeMake(240, 64);`

```
+ (UIButton *)buttonWithThemeAndFrame:(CGRect )frame title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:frame];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    NSString *defaultName = @"button_main_up";
    NSString *highlighted = @"button_main_down";
    [button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:defaultName] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:12.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:highlighted] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:12.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    button.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
    button.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    [button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    return button;
}
```

Note the yellow background is added to illustrate what size the button's frame actually is. Why isn't my image that size also?
[image]

Here is my button image:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your button image in photoshop and it looks like there is a transparency around the image and the size of the image is smaller than the canvas. The image is only 43x44 px with a transparent area around it.

I have clipped the transparent area. Try with this image.

[image]

Comment: Time to blame the designer... ;) Thanks

Comment: Drop shadow is missing in the attached image. Probably you need to add that outside this using photoshop.